# When preventing timing attacks, is it safe to exit on different lengths?

Tags: security, hash, bcrypt

In some libraries, for example [flask-bcrypt](https://github.com/passy/flask-bcrypt/blob/master/flaskext/bcrypt.py), we can see that the code exits early if the two strings are different lengths:

```python
def constant_time_compare(val1, val2):
    '''Returns True if the two strings are equal, False otherwise.

    The time taken is independent of the number of characters that match.
    '''

    if len(val1) != len(val2):
        return False

    result = 0
    for x, y in zip(val1, val2):
        result |= ord(x) ^ ord(y)

    return result == 0
```

Is this really safe? Surely this reveals to an attacker that the two strings were different lengths early and leaks information?

Answer (score 4):

> When preventing timing attacks, is it safe to exit on different lengths?

Generally no, but it's really dependent on the situation.

**The function itself**

This function will leak information with a timing attack regardless of the length comparison because it's running time is always dependent on the length of it's input.

With the length compare, the running time will change when both inputs are the same length.

Without the length compare, the running time will change based on the length of the shorter input (beause of `zip`). Once the attacker controlled input exceeds the length of the other input, running time will remain constant.

The running time of this function is so short though (unscientific testing shows less than 0.1ms for 32 bytes of input) that, in a real life situation, it would fairly difficult for an attacker to take advantage of this because of other factors such as variance in network latency. The attacker would probably need to already be on the machine where the code is executing to really make use of this weakness.

**Concerning flask-bcrypt**

In the context of flask-bcrypt though, this function is only used for comparing hashes, not direct user input. Because the hash length that bcrypt outputs is fixed, the `return False` should never actually execute. Hence, no timing attack exists for this function when used with bcrypt.

Flask-bcrypt uses this function for checking equality because the running time for normal string comparison in python (==) will change based on the content of the strings. Consider two nearly identical strings of the same length, if the first character of the two strings are different, == comparison will complete faster than if the difference occurs at the last character of the strings.

I would argue though that constant time string comparison is really unnecessary in this case. The goal of the attacker is to deduce the stored hash value based on processing time, the attacker needs to know what hash value is produced by their input to achieve this. The only way to know what hash is being produced though is for the attacker to know the workfactor and salt, and if they have this information then they already have the hash as well (because they're all stored together). In which case, there's no reason to perform the attack to begin with.